# defaultValue for input type 'date' is not working in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, date

I am using Nextjs and I would like to use the html tag, input type of 'date'. I also would like to set a defaultValue and I did something like this and it is not working:

```
const [dDate, setdDate] = useState('17/11/2022');


const ReactComponent = ()=>{
  
    return(
       
          <input type="date" className=" border-2 py-1 px-2 rounded-md" 
         onChange={(text)=>handleDepositeDate(text.target.value, index)} defaultValue={dDate} 
      />
     )

 };
```

It does not display on the screen. I also tried using `value` instead of `defaultValue`, still didn't work. I also tried other date input on the application and defaultValue didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different date format with the value attribute, like so:

```
<input type="date" value="2022-11-17"/>
```